# Computing $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ for $C_{n}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y^{n} \le x \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am looking for some help to understand the following because I am feeling really lost.

Say $$C_{n}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y^{n} \le x \}$$

then how can we find

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$

and

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}$$

My thoughts were to start off by listing some such as

$$C_{1}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y \le x \}$$
$$C_{2}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y^{2} \le x \}$$
$$C_{3}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : y^{3} \le x \}$$

for example, and drawing out the graphs. I also solved for x in those cases to see if I could use that.

I am just quite lost, I am not sure the way to best approach this.

Comment: It will probably be easier to imagine if you flip the axes around to the $y$-axis goes out to the right and the $x$ axis goes up. Then sketch the curves $x=y^n$ for some representative odd and even $n$. Now $\bigcap_nC_n$ is the part of the plane that is _above_ all of the curves, and $\bigcup_nC_n$ is the part of the plane that is above _at least one_ of the curves.

Comment: For n odd, all the pairs $(x, y)$ having $x \ge 0, y \le 0 $ are contained in $C_n$

Comment: Further, be aware that the regions you're looking for are somewhat complex -- they do not have _simple_ descriptions that you need to contort yourself to find. The best I can manage is to write the union as the union of three somewhat simple regions, and the intersection as the intersection of three somewhat simple regions -- but really the best form of an answer would probably be a graphical sketch.

Comment: Also, all the pairs from intersection have $|y| \le 1$

Answer (score 3):

**Overview**

Here is a visualization using the GeoGebra software:

[image: overview]

The purple curve and area is $y^{101} \le x$.
The blue curve and area is $y \le x$.

**Union**

First candidate for the union seems to be the union of the coloured areas here:

[image: union]

To get the two wanted sets precise one seems to need a good case distinction for each.

- First we have $C_1 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \le x \}$, thus the line $y = x$ and all points below
- For $x \in I_1 = (-\infty, -1)$ we note that the sets $C_k$ with odd $k$ (shown is $C_3 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^3 \le x \}$ in green) approach the half line $L_1 = \{ (x,-1) \mid x \in I_1 \}$ from below but do not reach $L_1$. That boundary $L_1$ is open. I used red dotted lines in the image above for such.
- For $x \in I_2 = (0,1)$ we note that the sets $C_k$ (all $k$) cover more and more of the area bounded by $L_2 = \{ (0,y) \mid y \in (0,1] \}$ and $L_3 = \{ (x,1) \mid x \in [0,1) \}$ and $y=x$ but do not reach $L_2$ or $L_3$.

**Intersection**

First candidate for the intersection seems to be the area bounded by the purple curves.

[image: intersection]

It is based on this overview:

[image: intersection idea]

Shown are $C_2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^2 \le x \}$ in cyan and
$C_4 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y^4 \le x \}$ in green.

On $I_2 = (0,1)$ for positive $y$ the line $y=x$ is the boundary and included in the intersection. For negative $y$ on $I_2$ the line $y^2 = x$ is the boundary.

On $I_3 = (1, \infty)$ all points from $I_3 \times [-1,1]$ are part of the intersection. This area is included in all $C_k$, especially the $C_k$ with even $k$ approach it from outside.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me. What does $A_n$ mean? And what is your definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle\text{some }set\text{ expression}\rangle$?

Comment: It doesn't lead to the correct union, at least. Note that the union contains some points that lie only in $C_1$ -- such as $(3,3)$ -- _as well as_ points that are only in $C_{2n+1}$ for large $n$ -- such as $(-3,-1-\varepsilon)$. There's not a single "limit" of the odd $C_i$s that can account for both classes of point.

Comment: Note that both of the points I mentioned need an _odd_ exponent -- but they need _different_ odd exponents. Basically your problem is that there's no good notion of a limit of a sequence of **sets** when (as here) the sequence is neither increasing nor decreasing.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are approaching it is correct.

- Identify the graphs that matter
- Sketch in the regions of the graphs, which correspond to points in the set
- Take the union/intersection of those regions

The function in question here is $y^n$, for all $n\ge1$. This takes on three major different forms, which you'll discover if you graph $y$ to a few powers.

Another helpful tip about these functions is that they always pass through (1,1) and (0,0), no matter how fast they grow.

Comment: How is this at all a helpful answer?

Comment: The OP is asking for direction, "I am lost". Not only is it the direct answer the OP is looking for, but more helpful than posting a solution.

Comment: Direct answer? How so? More helpful than posting a solution? How so? By all means, please share your solution.